# FutureBuilder inside ListView.builder not working

Tags: flutter, dart

Want to display items using FutureBuilder inside a ListView.builder. However, theres no display. help pls

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemExtent: 25.0,
    itemCount: _posts.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      Post post = _posts[index];
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(post.authorId),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return Container(
            height: 200.0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Do you have any error that could help us? You can try to check this medium to help you: https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-creating-a-listview-that-loads-one-page-at-a-time-c5c91b6fabd3

Comment: Possibly a problem due to `itemExtend (25) < 2*margin (10) + list padding`

Comment: Are you getting any result from the future?

Comment: someone says   "Your error message is very clear, " a build function returned null". In this case, the method that returns null is the anonymous function passed as the builder argument to the FutureBuilder. You're just missing the return keyword inside the else case because you're just creating the instance of Container but not returning it.".   but i have no idea wheres the missing return keyword, btw, i new to flutter, just month a ago when i started learning this.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts maam/sirs, i just the found the cause of it, its a silly error but i dont know, i misspelled ''userFOllowing" in this line  "QuerySnapshot followingSnapShot = await followingRef.document(userId).collection('userFollowing').getDocuments();" .whenever i create a post then save it to db, it won't save because i misspelled something , thats why  future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(post.authorId), is empty.